# Statistics and data analysis

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

1. What is meant by confidence interval in data analysis e.g. 95% confidence interval?
2. How does p<0.05 estimate significant difference?

Answer (score 0):

1. An interval, based on a sample, which has a $95$% probability of containing the unknown population parameter. Note that the interval is variable, but the unknown parameter is fixed.
2. Not sure what you mean. the word "significant" is used to describe the p value of 5%, just like "highly significant" is associated with a p value of 1%.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. First of all I wish to add that I am an amateur in statistics, I'm just trying to find my way around data analysis as it's caught my interest... What do you mean by 'unknown population parameter' and 'interval' when you say the interval is variable. 2.) would you explain what is meant by 'P value'?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the right place for a full explanation, and there are numerous sources online or in textbooks you can consult. Examples of an unknown population parameter: the mean of a normal distribution or the proportion of a binomial distribution which we want to estimate. The interval is variable because it depends on what sample we obtain to make the confidence interval. I hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, where would be more convenient, I like wechat, do you mind conversing there? Meanwhile I would appreciate recommendations to other sources.

Comment: Sure we can wechat

Comment: Ok send me your linked in contact I'll send my wechat id there

Comment: You can contact me directly on wechat

Comment: Ok, what's your wechat id?

Comment: It's David Quinn

Comment: Can't find any David Quinn except you didn't write it in English

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Its DavidCQuinn

Comment: Ok, I've sent a request